# REST API for inserting into Custom object which has a reference to another object

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am using the following coarse grained REST endpoint to insert multiple values into a custom object. But the customer object has references to another object. For example, it has a field Contact__c which references a contact while the JSON object for input has only an externalContactID field(which is one of the custom fields in the standard object 'Contacts'). Of course the following code below is not going to do that. How can I incorporate this into the apex code without a processing overhead. (NOTE: I intentionally do not want to do this using BULK API)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MultiTicket/*')
global with sharing class MultiTicketRestController{
   global class RequestBody {
       global List<Ticket__c> tickets;
   }

    @HttpPost   
    global static List<Ticket__c> createBulk(MultiTicketRestController.RequestBody req) {
        insert req.tickets; 
        return req.tickets;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the value of the linked objects so a high level / coarse grained example:

Instead of `insert req.tickets`

get the value of the `externalContactID` field in the request body then

```
req.tickets.Contact__r = New Contact(EXTERNALIDFIELD__c = externalContactID);
insert req.tickets;
```

Comment: note that you don't have to use upsert to use external Ids to resolve Foreign Keys fields, they work on insert/update as well.

Comment: @superfell - Yes you are correct. Updated to reflect that